# Necessity of Galerkin Approximation in Existence Proof for Parabolic PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm studying the proof of the existence of solutions to linear parabolic PDEs, e.g. the heat equation $u_t = \Delta u + f$. The standard technique seems to be to do a Galerkin approximation, see e.g. Section 6.5 in [these notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf).

My question is: In the notes [mentioned above](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf), a proof of the existence of solutions in the finite dimensional case is given (see Proposition 6.5), but I do not see where this proof makes use of the fact that the system is finite dimensional. If this were not required, however, then what's the point in making a Galerkin approximation in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. The proof is based on showing that the map
$$
\Phi(u) := u_0 + \int_0^t \Delta u + f \, dt
$$
is a contraction and hence has a fixed point. In the infinite-dimensional problem, this definition of $\Phi$ doesn't make sense since $\Delta : H^1_0 \to H^{-1}$ and thus it is not clear what the domain and range of $\Phi$ should be. In the finite-dimensional system, on the other hand, we replace $\Delta$ by an operator $\Delta_n : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and everything works out.

Comment: Actually, this can't be the answer. We could compose every term in the definition of $\Phi$ with the Riesz map $R : H^{-1} \to H^1_0$ and interpret $\Phi$ as a function from $H^1_0$ onto itself...

Comment: But you are on the right track. The essence of the method is exactly that in finite dimension you can solve every linear equation, essentially because all finite-dimensional operators are bounded. So you can solve the approximate equation with $\Delta_n$. You will later have to prove some estimates that allow you to pass to the infinite dimensional limit.

Comment: But $\Delta : H^1_0 \to H^{-1}$ is bounded as well, and this boundedness is preserved by the Riesz map.

Comment: Doesn't work, for the reason you wrote. The equation $u'=Au$ is trivial IF $A\colon H\to H$ is a bounded linear operator (actually, Lipschitz continuous is enough). Note $H\to H$: same domain, same range. The fact that $A\colon H_+\to H_-$, where $H_+\subset H\subset H_-$, is a bounded linear operator is useless. All non-pathological linear operators are continuous on their domain, if it is equipped with a particular norm. Yet not all linear equations are solvable. (Remark. By "Non-pathological" I mean "closed").

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am still not convinced though. In the above case, we know $H_- = H_+'$, so I can get a bounded linear operator $R \circ A : H_+ \to H_+$ using the Riesz map $R$.

Comment: Yes. Problem is, $RA$ is trivial: $RA=I_{H_+}$. You have already used the Riesz map to define $A$.

Comment: $RA = I_{H_+}$ indeed holds and is very fascinating! I intuitively understand that this should be a problem, but still don't see the details why. You mentioned the advantage in finite dimensions is that all linear operators are bounded. I don't see where this enters in our discussion though. It rather seems like in finite dimensions, $V$ and its dual $V'$ are related in some manner which is different in infinite dimensions.

Comment: Well, let us forget all details for a moment. Whatever our definition of "solution" is, a solution to $u'=Au$ MUST be different from a solution to $u'=u$. This means that your program of using the Riesz map $R\colon H_+' \to H_+$ must fail somewhere. (This is actually a know subtlety of Hilbert space theory: sometimes, one cannot "identify" a Hilbert space and its dual, but must keep them on separate grounds. If you want more details, see [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q&f=false) (pag.136-137) )